# iOS11 - Indefinitely run an app on background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I need to design an app that match people.

1. User A mark a place as "i'm here." with a specific range e.g. 150m.
2. User B marks a place with a range, which includes user A.
3. If they are in their ranges with their marked locations, then a match will be made.
4. If any of the users is not in their range. Then the user will not get matched with the newcomer users.

With this requirements, I have lots of challenges faced on.

If user A marks his place and if he is goes away from the region, `CoreLocation` includes a function like **Region Monitoring**. So i can track user's exits of their region whenever occurs. And its really a good feature which wakes up the app even the app is in the suspended or terminated state.

If all users have active internet connection, there is no problem at all.
So if any of the users internet connection is lost and then users exit their region, so they can not send their exit region notification which is already provided by `CoreLocation` Region Monitoring, to the Node server.

But if user marks a coordinate with region then the users exits already with a time that the user was no internet connection, the `exitRegion` info will not be sent. So the user will get a match even not in the range.

So in this situation, before any match i need to ping the users like "Hey are you there" or `regionState` provided by Region Monitoring.

The problem starts here,

As an idea, i suppose that i can use silent notifications and if i don't get reponse from the client after 30 secs of limited background work after app is awake, i can consider it "i don't know that if the user is already in its region" then not produce a match. But whenever a newcomer comes to the MongoDB, i can not send silent notification to all clients.

Apple says that;

> Silent notifications are not meant as a way to keep your app awake in
>   the background, nor are they meant for high priority updates. APNs
>   treats silent notifications as low priority and may throttle their
>   delivery altogether if the total number becomes excessive. The actual
>   limits are dynamic and can change based on conditions, but try not to
>   send more than a few notifications per hour.

So i can not guarantee that the silent notification will reach and i can not send silent notification continuously. And what happens if the silent notification expire?

I can keep an open connection per client with socket io in background. So Apple again restricts background operations as a limited of time. iOS my kill my app from background state and my open connection is lost when the phone is in locked state and i can see the client as offline even it has active internet connection.

If i use the authorization of specific background modes like voip to determine user has active internet connection but app is terminated, waking up the app and sending response to the server. But then Apple will reject my app. Because i'm not a voip app.

I need a solution to send ping to every client to determine whether they have are still in their range. If i dont get an response due to lost internet of client than i will prevent for future matches.

If i success this behavior, when user open apps with a active internet connection, then i can update the user's matches when was offline from logged informations. Like you were got matches 2 hours ago with another user but you missed some due to your `exitRegion`.

So what i need to do ask every client if they are in their region if they have no active internet connection?

Thanks,

Comment: "So what i need to do ask every client if they are in their region if they have no active internet connection" Magic?

Comment: Lol. You're right. But do you have any suggestion to solve this situation? Or simply make the app is not usable when no internet connection. So in this state users who marks place will not get a match when they were offline?

Comment: Look at Find My Friends. If my friend's location can't be found (perhaps their phone ran out of juice), it says we can't get a location and might show the last location we _did_ have.

Comment: Well data can't be transfered without a medium. There's few options besides internet, bluetooth etc..

Comment: OK, so if no internet connection is alive on any client. I can prevent the client for new matches. But If the client has internet and app is suspended, then is there a way to wake the app?

Comment: You can use location updates to enable you to send location data to your server. You can use silent push notifications to notify your app of updates in its area. If the user isn’t online then they are going to have stale data. You can age data on the local device and in the server and throw it away if it hasn’t been updated for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Look into background modes for swift. Specifically, location updates which will wake your app up if the user's location updates. You can find more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: It is hard to achieve that monitoring the user's exit of region when they are offline to prevent new matches. I think there is some wrong things in my app's logic. Or i'm demanding something is not possible technically.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like iBeacons could be part of your solution. Have all users of your app broadcast a specific iBeacon when they're running it, and set up a beacon region to listen for your app's broadcasts. When the device detects one, it will notify your app, and will even launch it if it's not running when the beacon is detected.